# Apollo GraphQL: MQTT Subscribe to a Broker to just provide the published data

Tags: node.js, graphql, mqtt, apollo-server, graphql-subscriptions

### Scenario

I have a sensor node which publishes information on a specific MQTT Topic (sent to a Mosquitto broker). The data sent is a pure string.

#### Backend

currently I am using `apollo-server-express` to build a GraphQL Server. I wish to use [`graphql-mqtt-subscriptions](https://github.com/davidyaha/graphql-mqtt-subscriptions) to:

- Subscribe to the MQTT Broker
- Read the information on a specific topic and just return it to the `graphiql` UI

`dependencies`

```
"dependencies": {
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.8.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "graphql": "^14.4.2",
    "graphql-mqtt-subscriptions": "^1.1.0",
    "graphql-subscriptions": "^1.1.0",
    "graphql-tools": "^4.0.5",
    "mqtt": "^3.0.0",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.16"
  },
```

### Code Snippets

the entrypoint `server.js` code:

```
import express from 'express';
import {ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import { typeDefs } from './graphql/schema';
import { resolvers } from './graphql/resolvers';
import { createServer } from 'http';


const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers});

const app = express();

server.applyMiddleware({ app });

const httpServer = createServer(app);

server.installSubscriptionHandlers(httpServer);

httpServer.listen({port: 4000}, () => {
    console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000/${server.graphqlPath}`)
    console.log(` Subscriptions ready at ws://localhost:4000/${server.subscriptionsPath}`)
});
```

the `typeDefs` Schema for GraphQL is the following:

```
type Result {
        data: String
}

type Subscription {
        siteAdded(topic: String): Result
    }

schema {
  query: Query
  mutation: Mutation
  subscription: Subscription
}
```

where `siteAdded(topic: String)` will take the topic the MQTT needes to subscribe to. Example:

```
subscription {
   siteAdded(topic: "test/1/env") {
       data
   }
```

The `resolvers.js` looks like the following (as mentioned in may documentations):

```
import { MQTTPubSub } from 'graphql-mqtt-subscriptions';
import { connect } from 'mqtt';

const client = connect('mqtt://my.mqtt.broker.ip.address', {
    reconnectPeriod: 1000,
});

const pubsub = new MQTTPubSub({
    client
});

export const resolvers: {
Subscription: {
        siteAdded: {
            subscribe: (_, args) => {
                console.log(args.topic); // to check if this gets called or not.
                pubsub.asyncIterator([args.topic]);

            }
        }
    }
};
```

### Inference

the `console.log` on the `args.topic` gets called but after that the following error in `graphiql`:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Subscription field must return Async Iterable. Received: undefined"
  }
}
```

If I perform a `return pubsub.asyncIterator()`:

It provides the timely data from the Broker but the output is `null`:

```
{
  "data": {
    "siteAdded": null
  }
}
```

I have added the Websockets middleware in the `server.js` mentioned above according to the [Apollo Docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/subscriptions/)

Where Am I going wrong here and how to just add the data coming from the subscribed topic to `graphiql`?

Comment: You forgot to call `return` in your subscribe resolver. `return pubsub.asyncIterator([args.topic]);`

Comment: @Dom I tried it it doesn't work. The UI keeps sending HTTP POST but no data

Comment: You definitely need to `return` the result of calling `pubsub.asyncIterator()` like @Dom said. How are you testing the subscription? Once you subscribe in Playground, you'll need to trigger the `publish` call somehow (for example, by opening Playground in another tab and sending a mutation that calls `publish`)

Comment: @DanielRearden but since the sensor is already publishing on the topic wouldn't that provide me something? I actually don't have a mutation that triggers `publish`. I already have a sensor that publishes on the topic `test/1/env` and since I use `test/+/env` wildcard the data should be available

Comment: Ah I see. I would rig up a dummy mutation that calls `publish` and at least see if that works as expected. Assuming it does, then you can debug from there. Maybe there's a mismatch in the topic names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Summary

### Update

- `graphql-mqtt-subscriptions`: `v1.2.0` now provides wild card parsing support
- [Documented a practical usage of MQTT and GraphQL](https://medium.com/@shantanoodesai/live-iot-data-subscription-with-apollo-graphql-and-mqtt-60b7c5a86cde)

### Caveats

- The wildcards like `+` and `#` in the `graphql-mqtt-subscriptions` v1.1.0 on the NPM Registry are not available. However, the repository has the implementations already. The owner of the repository needs to update the registry. See [Open Issue for `graphql-mqtt-subscriptions`](https://github.com/davidyaha/graphql-mqtt-subscriptions/issues/9)
- I am currently using a complete topic for the MQTT Subscription in order to get the data from the sensor e.g. `test/1/env` as opposed to `test/+/env`

### Development Update

- Previously I was sending data from the sensor in a raw string format (plain-text), hence I updated the firmware to send data in JSON String as follows:

  ```
    {"data": "temp=23,humid=56 1500394302"}
  ```

### Solution

1. As mentioned in the comments by @Dom and @DanielRearden I forget initially to add `return` if I used the curly brackets `{}`. e.g.:

   ```
       Subscription: {
       siteAdded: {
           subscribe: (_, args) => {
               console.log(args.topic); // to check if this gets called or not.
               return pubsub.asyncIterator([args.topic]);

           }
       }
   }
   ```

   or I just removed the brackets and `return` by writing the resolver as follows:

   ```
       Subscription: {
          siteAdded: {
              subscribe: (_, args) => pubsub.asyncIterator([args.topic]),
          }
       }
   ```

   This was still returning me `null` as mentioned in the query.
2. I was able to obtain the data from the subscription by following the [Payload Transformation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-subscriptions/subscriptions-to-schema/#payload-transformation) documentation for Apollo where within my resolvers I did the following:

   ```
      Subscription: {
       siteAdded: {
           resolve: (payload) => {
               return {
                   data: payload.data,
               };
           },
           subscribe: (_, args) => pubsub.asyncIterator([args.topic]),
       }
   }
   ```

   The payload had to be resolved accordingly for the Schema.

### Result

Now a subscription as follows work like a charm:

```
    subscription {
        siteAdded(topic: "test/1/env") {
            data
        }
    }
```

provides the following result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "siteAdded": {
      "data": "temp=27.13,humid=43.33 1565345004"
    }
  }
}
```